# How I can insert picture into excel cell in express js

Tags: node.js, express, export-to-excel

I am working on a project, where I need to insert picture into an excel cell. I found many node packages that allow us to insert picture into excel, but could not find a package to insert picture into an excel cell.

[image]

Right now I am using xlsx package, to convert JSON data into excel sheet

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

let data = {name: 'Rizwan', age: 25}
const workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
const workBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, 'students');
// Generate buffer
XLSX.write(workBook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });

// Binary string
XLSX.write(workBook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });

XLSX.writeFile(workBook, search_term + '.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many node packages, that can be used to insert pictures into an excel sheet like [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs), [excel4node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node), or [excellent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excellent). But, my requirement was to insert picture into the cell of the excel sheet. [libxl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxl) package can be used to insert picture into the excel cell.

Comment: Can you provide a solution, buddy ?